# How to update label value from another form?

Tags: c#, forms

I am trying to make an RPG game and I have some issues updating a label with "Player's health". I have two forms. The first one is called "Game" and it contains the following code.

```
private void Battle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Battle battle = new Battle();
        battle.Show();
    }

    public void Game_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HeroMaker.wizardChoosen)
        {
            wizard = new Wizard(HeroMaker.className);
            NameLabel.Text = HeroMaker.className;
            HealthLabel.Text = wizard.Health.ToString();
        }
    }
```

That form creates my class and fill the name and health labels with the Player's name and health. When I click the button Battle, it creates a new form in which I can fight with some creatures. Here comes the second form

```
private void AttackTroll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Game.wizard.DoBattle(troll); // Attacks a troll which has 40 return damage, and player health is 200.
        MessageBox.Show(Game.wizard.Health.ToString()); // Shows that player health is now 160 (working fine).
        Game newGame = new Game(); // Making a new form to get accses to the label I need (thats the only way I know).
        newGame.HealthLabel.Text = Game.wizard.Health.ToString(); // This is suposed to update the label from 200 to 160, BUT IT STAYS AT 200.
        newGame.Show(); // Help me, please.
    }
```

This button Attacks a creature which has return damage. The problem is that I need to update the "HealthLabel" in the first form with the new value, but I can't manage to do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly common point of confusion. You're instantiating a second `Game` form that has nothing to do with the original `Game` instance.

Instead, modify your `Battle` Form so you can pass a reference to the `Game` Form to it:

```
public class Battle : Form
{
    private Form game;

    public Battle(Form game)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.game = game;
    }
```

Modify your `Game` Form so there's a method that updates the Label:

```
public class Game : Form
{
    public void UpdateHealth(string health)
    {
        HealthLabel.Text = health;
    }
```

Now your `Battle` class can use the reference and the public method, and you don't need to create a second instance of `Game`.

```
game.UpdateHealth(Game.wizard.Health.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did everything you said. Everything seem fine, but now when I click the Attack button it gives me a NullReference Exception. http://prntscr.com/9dw1zh

Comment: This line throws the exception >> game.UpdateHealth(Game.wizard.Health.ToString());

Comment: Yes,I did everything you told me to do. I can show you the code if that would help?

Comment: By empty you mean the constructor with the "InitializeComponent();" ?

Comment: Okay, but now it doesn't want to create a new form when I click the Battle button in the Game form, since it wants 1 argument inside it ?

Comment: You're incredible. I was struggling for days. Sorry, for being newbie. I am kinda new in this world. Thank you!

Comment: You may want to look at my two form project that I just posted : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34258994/how-does-one-window-udpate-datagrid-of-the-other-window-by-using-wpf-with-mvvm/34259149#34259149